# when I do a redirect, there is an error undefined method `empty?' for 15:Fixnum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

when I do a redirect, there is an error undefined method `empty?' for 15:Fixnum

I updated rails with 4.0.0 before 4.0.3 version. Now tormented by this bug.

What could it be?

projects_controller.rb

```
def create
    @project = Project.new(permited_params)

  if @project.save
    current_user.set_role :owner, @project
    redirect_to project_memberships_url(@project)
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

**redirect_to project_memberships_url(@project)** the error here.

**stacktrace [Gist](https://gist.github.com/vadus1/9514613)**

Comment: Can you share the error stacktrace.

Comment: Have you overwritten `to_param` method on `Project` model?

Comment: Can you share how you have defined the routes for `project` resource.

Comment: @Vimsha  Yes, `def to_param; id; end`

Comment: @KirtiThorat  `resources :projects do; resources :memberships; end`

Comment: The error is because of `to_param` as @Vimsha was suggesting.

Comment: Make it return String : `def to_param; id.to_s; end`

Comment: I guess you'll also need to change `redirect_to project_memberships_url(@project)` to `redirect_to project_memberships_url(project_id: @project.id)`

Comment: The second method will not work, because the @project.id sets a constraint on the ability to use slug as key ways.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update `to_param` in the `Project` model as below:

```
def to_param
  id.to_s
end
```

`to_param` should return a `String` and not a `Fixnum`.